# Angular 8 - Form Input set validation rule with attribute or variable

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I want to create a form where I can change the validation rule of `Validators.required` via attribute or an boolean variable inside the html view. Is it possible? For example:

`<input type="text" formControlName="example" validate="true">`

The reason for the question. I show up different form sets for different page requests. And for example, by changing the select value from VAL1 to VAL2, VAL2 has some diffrent fields where are requiered but not the same like VAL1.

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance A.

Comment: Since you are using reactive form you can set validation dynamically in ts file. Is there any specific reason for doing in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can have a `validationCondition` (**boolean**) in your form. Then you can dynamically set the validation according to the value returned by your `validationCondition`.

An example would be,

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    validationCondition: [''],
    example: ['']
});

const exampleControl = this.form.get('example');

this.form.get('validationCondition').valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
    if (change) {
        exampleControl.setValidators(Validators.required);
        exampleControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    } else {
        exampleControl.setValidators(null);
        exampleControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
});
```

References,

1. [updateValueAndValidity()](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#!#updateValueAndValidity-anchor)
2. [valueChanges](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#valueChanges)
3. [FormControl methods](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#methods)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this where you change the validators upon changing the form set toggle:

```
public formSetChanged(newVal) {
    const exampleField = this.form.get('exampleField');
    exampleField.setValidators(newVal === 1 ? [Validators.required] : null);
    exampleField.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```